# What do state features mean in the context of inverse RL?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, terminology, papers, features, inverse-rl

I am reading Zeibart's Inverse RL [paper](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/2008/AAAI08-227.pdf), and it states -

> The agent is assumed to be attempting to optimize some function that linearly maps the features of each state, $f_{sj} \in \mathbb{R}^k$, to a state reward value representing the agent’s utility for visiting that state."

Can someone please give me an example of state features? I would highly appreciate it if it is in the context of this GitHub [repo](https://github.com/MatthewJA/Inverse-Reinforcement-Learning/blob/master/irl/maxent.py), wherein the author coded the `feature_matrix` as a diagonal matrix of shape $N \times D$, where $N$ represents states and $D$ features.

Comment: Yeah i was also facing this problem.
If you knew this plz talk with me here.